# Why Cerebrospinal fluid is not heated for VDRL?

Tags: human-biology, microbiology, lab-techniques, neurology

For performing VDRL of serum , we heat serum to inactivate complement proteins which may otherwise interfere , but why don't we do same for CSF even though it too has complement proteins in it?

Is it because of lesser stability of WBCs in CSF( which is hypotonic) and on heating may rupture to release cardiolipin? But I can't comprehend how its worse than having complement proteins?